# How do I configure TFS to get latest versions of specified branches on machine startup?

Tags: configuration

The defined activity for team on every day before start work is fetch latest code from the TFS. However it is manual as of now. We would like make it automate. How can we configure TFS to fetch latest code of specified folder or Branch on start up of the machine?

**Edit based on response:**
Why this configuration is required?
Most of the times developers forgot to fetch the latest code and missing updates. I would like to reduce burden on developers by making it to automatic task instead of manual.

Comment: "How can we configure TFS to fetch latest code of specified folder or Branch on start up of the machine" - I wonder why that might be a bad idea....

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this sounds like a problematic solution. There are a number of issues with doing this:

- Bad code in repository will break everyones local workspaces
- If code has been checked in which conflicts with local changes, the developer is forced to resolve them
- If a developer is doing refactoring, he is forced to hunt down old use in code when getting latest (this does not result in conflicts, but compilation/runtime errors)

There are probably more problems, and this is why getting latest should be left up to the developer as a conscious decision.

You might consider other approaches, such as:

- Check-in policies which requires getting latest and building
- Continuous integration builds, which will show if bad code has been checked in
- Gated check-in, which will make it impossible to check in code which does not compile/test

But. If you really want to automate a get latest, you should be able to set up a scheduled task which runs the command line:

```
tf get /recursive "WORKSPACEPATH"
```